# How to fix CopyFromRecordset error in vbscript?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, vbscript

Executing a macro from VBScript gives error :

> Method CopyFromRecordset of object 'Range' failed

But It works fine, when I execute same from Excel workbook.

I tried executing from Excel workbook and it worked fine.

Here Is My VBA Code:

```vb
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection 
conn.connectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;INITIAL CATALOG=DEVDB; INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

str = "exec SP_Getcustomers @RequestID=" & requestID
rs.Open str, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

If Not IsEmptyRecordset(rs) Then
    rs.MoveFirst

    'Populate the first row of the sheet with recordset’s field names
    i = 0
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Customer Table").Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields.Item(i).Name
        i = i + 1
    Next fld
    'Populate the sheet with the data from the recordset
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Customer Table").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs  
End If
```

VB Script Code:

```vb
Dim path, macroname
path = ""
path = Wscript.Arguments.Item(2) 
macroname = ""
macroname = Wscript.Arguments.Item(3)



Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'" & path & "'!" & macroname,     WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Are you sure you run this as a VBScript? Please clarify! Please also note that VBScript and VBA are 2 completely different things and you cannot copy VBA code into a vbs file and expect that to work out of the box. These are completely different languages (just with a *similar* syntax).

Comment: I wouldn't say that the languages are *completely* different, since they are relatively closely related to each other, but there certainly are [notable differences](https://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml).

Comment: This is my VBA code. My VBScript code below:

Dim path, macroname
path = ""
path = Wscript.Arguments.Item(2) 
macroname = ""
macroname = Wscript.Arguments.Item(3)



Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'" & path & "'!" & macroname, WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Well, that's an argueable point of view. I like to consider them as completely different with some similarities (especially in Syntax), since therey are fundamentally different in some points by design: Eg. VBScript is not compiled but an interpreted language while VBA is compiled which makes it much slower than VBA. VBScript is untyped (everyting is a Variant), you cannot create classes and objects. Just to name 2 of the big differences.

Comment: @SachinB Please [edit] your question to add the code instead of posting it in a comment. Comments with code are not good to read.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for correcting and formatting

Comment: Your VBA code and VBScript code are not similar at all. In your VBA code, you are connecting to a DB whereas in your VBScript code, you are attempting to call a macro (which presumably does the same job). Without seeing what your connection string is or how you are connecting to `other app`, it would be difficult to decipher. @Pᴇʜ/Ansgar: VBScript Vs VBA Vs VB.Net. age long conversation :). Although if memory serves me wright, I think MS class them as `different` languages.. could be wrong though

Comment: @Zac Actually I think the OP just calls the VBA macro with VBScript. And it should not be the same. But it behaves different if the run was initiated by VBScript.

Comment: @Zac When I execute macro from Excel sheet then it executes with no problem. but, when i call from vbscript then only I get this error.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: that's exactly what I was trying to get to. When called from a script, it could be the initialisation of connection that's failing and hence the error msg. Without looking at the connection code, it would be difficult to pinpoint the issue. Sachin, can you post the connection code in your VBA?

Comment: Set conn = New ADODB.Connection 
conn.connectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;INITIAL CATALOG=DEVDB; INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"

Comment: updated in post.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I think you are mistaken about classes and objects in VBScript. I have defined and used my own classes in VBScript.

Comment: @GeertBellekens whoops, you are right classes are implemented since version 5.0. Thanks for correcting me. It's been a while since I used vbscript ;)

Comment: @Zac: Any clue what might be the problem ?

Comment: How is `requestID` set?